# scrapy selector xpath extract matching regex or slicing string

Tags: python, regex, xpath, scrapy, selector

I am a newbie in scrapy and a bit on Python.

I want to retrieve item['rating']. The rating is in a form of a string "rating is 4" but I want only the number... How can I get it?

I tought about these to solutions below, but dont know if they make any sense. And none are working.

```
> item_pub['rating'] = review.xpath('/html/body//*/div[@class="details"]/table[@class="detailtoptable"]/tbody/tr[1]/td/img/@alt').re(r'\d+') #to extract only the number since the result with extract() would be "rating is 4"
```

or

```
 > item_pub['rating'] = review.xpath('/html/body//*/div[@class="details"]/table[@class="detailtoptable"]/tbody/tr[1]/td/img/@alt')[-1:].extract() #to extract only the number since the result with extract() would be "rating is 4"
```

thanks so much for the help and sorry for my english, I hope my problem was clear.

Comment: post a sample html file.

Comment: <td>
<img alt="rating is 4" title="rating is 4" src="/Shared\images\ratingstars_web8.gif"/>
</td>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way of thinking is ok, to use regex. You just have a bad Xpath.
Here are a few tips:

- no need to do `/html/body//`, you can just do `//`
- no need to select all elements with `//*` just to later select a single element. You can just go ahead and select the desired element: `//div`
- if you found this xpath using a browser, most likely there is no really a `tbody` element, since browsers add those often

Try it like this:

```
item_pub['rating'] = review.xpath('//div[@class="details"]/table[@class="detailtoptable"]/tr[1]/td/img/@alt').re_first(r'\d+')
```

Comment: There is `re_first` method when you expect single value.

Answer (score 0):

Through Beautiful Soup, you could do like this,

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = '''<td> <img alt="rating is 4" title="rating is 4" src="/Shared\images\ratingstars_web8.gif"/> </td>'''
>>> [re.search(r'\d+', i['alt']).group() for i in soup.select('td > img[alt*="rating"]')]
['4']
```